# Search for character in pixel of a image in android

Tags: java, android

I am working on an app where i need to get the pixels of a frame and then search for a character in the pixel. I am able to get the pixels of the image however I am not able to find out the way to search for a character 's' in the pixel which has been encoded in to the frame of the video I am capturing. I am fining the pixels using the following code:

package com.example.;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // a Bitmap that will act as a handle to the image
    private Bitmap bmp;

    // an integer array that will store ARGB pixel values
    private int[][] rgbValues;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // load the image and use the bmp object to access it
        Log.v("MainActivity", "In on create");
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test);
        Log.v("MainActivity", "bmp created:" + bmp);
        // define the array size
        rgbValues = new int[bmp.getWidth()][bmp.getHeight()];

        // Print in LogCat's console each of one the RGB and alpha values from
        // the 4 corners of the image
        // Top Left
        Log.v("MainActivity",
                "Top Left pixel: " + Integer.toHexString(bmp.getPixel(0, 0)));
        // Top Right
        Log.v("MainActivity",
                "Top Right pixel: " + Integer.toHexString(bmp.getPixel(31, 0)));
        // Bottom Left
        Log.v("MainActivity",
                "Bottom Left pixel: "
                        + Integer.toHexString(bmp.getPixel(0, 31)));
        // Bottom Right
        Log.v("MainActivity",
                "Bottom Right pixel: "
                        + Integer.toHexString(bmp.getPixel(31, 31)));

        // get the ARGB value from each pixel of the image and store it into the
        // array
        for (int i = 0; i < bmp.getWidth(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < bmp.getHeight(); j++) {
                // This is a great opportunity to filter the ARGB values
                rgbValues[i][j] = bmp.getPixel(i, j);

            }
        }
        Log.v("MainActivity", "RGB values:" + rgbValues);

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) is what you want

Comment: @ Sharp edge: OCR is not what I need because text is not in the image but it 's been encoded in to the frame of the video using matlab. Its gotta something to do with rgb values I believe...

Comment: @SanjeevKumar you mean [Steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography)?

Comment: What do you exactly mean with 'has been encoded in to the frame of the video'? What is the technology?

Comment: @chris: I mean using matlab i have encoded the video with string...when the app runs it captures the frames and it must find the that encoded string..

Comment: @Sanjeev Kumar: is there some doc for this anywhere? I never used this before